# How to use the string inside brackets

Tags: ios, objective-c

From another answer I got this code:

```
NSURLSession *aSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[aSession dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
if (((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode == 200) {
    if (data) {
        NSString *contentOfURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", contentOfURL);
    }
}
}] resume];
```

Now I want to use String "contentOfURL" outside the brackets and XCode doesn't let me use it... Why? When I want do for example this:

```
NSURLSession *aSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[aSession dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
if (((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode == 200) {
    if (data) {
        NSString *contentOfURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", contentOfURL);
    }
}
}] resume];

NSLog(@"%@", contentOfURL); //than here it shows me an error...
```

My question is, how to use String "contentOfURL" outside the brackets...
Thank you for questions

Comment: NSString *sample = @"http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";  [[aSession dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sample] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
}]] resume];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that and it wouldn't work if you managed to work around the syntax problems.

First, the syntax problem. Variable declarations are scoped. They are meaningful only within the immediately enclosing context. If they are inside a compound statement (`{` … `}`), then the variable is only defined from the point of its declaration until the end of the compound statement (the closing `}`). If they are at file scope (outside of any method or function), then they are valid from the point of declaration to the bottom of the file.

Now, the conceptual problem:

You are asking an `NSURLSession` to create an `NSURLSessionDataTask` by calling `-dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:` on it. An `NSURLSessionDataTask` is a long-running task and it is **asynchronous**. You are passing a "block" as the completion handler. This block is an encapsulated chunk of code and data. It's an object. A copy of it is held by the new `NSURLSessionDataTask` and is not called until the data task has completed.

So, `contentOfURL` has no value until long after the `NSLog()` statement you added at the end of your code snippet.

You have asked a long-running task to begin. It is asynchronous, which means your code goes on without waiting for it to complete. You are then attempting to access the results in the next statement. But there are no results, yet. The long-running task has barely gotten started, let alone completed.

You need to really adjust your thinking to wrap your head around asynchronous code. If you want to do something with the end result of an asynchronous task, you need to put the "do something" code in the completion handler or (for APIs that work this way) some observer code that's watching for the notification that the task has completed.

You can't write code that just assumes the task started by one statement is complete by the next statement. (The first *statement* has completed, but the task *started by* that statement has not.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `contentsOfURL` outside the brackets, like this:

```
NSString *contentOfURL;
NSURLSession *aSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[aSession dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
if (((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode == 200) {
    if (data) {
        contentOfURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", contentOfURL);
    }
}
}] resume];

NSLog(@"%@", contentOfURL);
```

If you define `contentsOfURL` inside the block, the scope of the variable will remain inside the block; therefore, you need to declare the variable outside the function.

Comment: This is not just a normal case of variable scoping and compound statements (`{ ... }`). The original code had `contentOfURL` declared in an Objective-C "block" that is submitted to an asynchronous API. By moving the declaration out of that block, you make the final `NSLog()` statement legal, although `contentOfURL` will always be `nil` there. But the assignment to `contentOfURL` inside the block is now illegal because blocks capture `const` copies of variables from outside scopes. And, even if it were legal, the assignment would not happen before the `NSLog()` statement.

Comment: @KenThomases thank you for pointing that out. You're absolutely right.